# How to overwrite Database on MySQL Foreign key

Tags: mysql

I created a simple 2 tables to experiment foreign keys, but when I input values into the Foreign table it does not overwrite current columns.

```
create table testing2 (balance bigint, stud int, FOREIGN KEY (stud) REFERENCES testing(stud));
insert into testing2 values ('4000','0','1');
insert into testing2 values ('4000','2000','1');
```

The result would show all the values inserted, I want to overwrite it on my last insert

Comment: The inserts should fail because you have more values than columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overwrite values just use UPDATE instead of INSERT.
Also, why are you trying to insert 3 values in a table with 2 columns?

Comment: I'm sorry my DB was updated with 3 columns, Thanks I'll try right away

Comment: 'update testing2 set balance_paid = 500060, balance = 50060 where stud = 1;'